# Replace part of a Line in a File

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to search for a line in the file using a pattern and partially replace it

the word "tribual" is unique in the file

the file looks like this:

```
userfile
indirect
/home/test
15238 8687 45688
stats 887 558 998
tribual 45688 786661 786661 -223811
home test
indirect test 1048576
indirect backup 45688
```

I would like to replace the line tribual, whereby the 2nd digit 1048576 must not be changed!

example:

```
old:
tribual 45688 786661 786661 -223811
new:
tribual 45688 1048576 1048576 1048576
```

the 2nd digit 45688 is always different.

I don't know how I can leave out the 2nd digit to replace it

```
import os

arr = os.listdir('/opt/files/')
for ufiles in arr:
    f = open(ufiles, 'r')
    filedata = f.read()
    f.close()

    newdata = filedata.replace('tribual 45688 786661 786661 -223811', 'tribual 45688 1048576 1048576 1048576')

    f = open(ufiles, 'w')
    f.write(newdata)
    f.close()
```

many thanks for the help

Comment: *"the 2nd digit 1048576"* ... *"the 2nd digit 45688"* -- those are numbers, not digits, and why are you calling them both the 2nd? Please [edit] to clarify. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Sidenote: best practice for opening files is using `with` like `with open(filename) as f: data = f.read()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expression:

```
import re

newdata = re.sub(
    r'^(tribual \S+).*$',
    r'\1 1048576 1048576 1048576',
    filedata,
    flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Breakdown:

- `^` - Start of line (with `re.MULTILINE`)
- `(...)` - Match group, which is then retrieved with `\1` in the replacement pattern
- `\S+` - One or more non-whitespace characters, i.e. `'45688'` in this case
- `.*` - Anything
- `$` - End of line (with `re.MULTILINE`)

Docs: [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

Try it online: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bYsgw4/1)